# Searching for Gray Log 2 API or a way to query ElasticSearch

Tags: java, .net, elasticsearch, graylog2

I have a question regarding [Gray Log 2](http://graylog2.org/)

In the company I work for all systems report exceptions to Gray Log server which has predefined streams.

I need to build an external Dashboard which retrieves data from different streams.
I haven't found any Gray Log 2 API to use for this. I read that there is a possibility to query Elastic Search directly. Can you please advise how do I do so or if there is any Gray Log 2 API.

My Dashboard will be written or in JSF or in .NET still not sure about which is best to use.

I would be very grateful for detailed answer on this question. Links will help too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graylog2 has a very clear and complete Restful API, that you can browse/test with Swagger.

Go to System -> Nodes and select "API Browser" from a node action dropdown menu.

By default, you can access it at the following url : http://your.graylog2:12900/api-browser

Hope this helps !

Comment: the port for graylog api is 129000. This worked for me:  http://your.graylog2:129000/api-browser

Comment: Comment above isn't correct. Default port is 12900. Every port number is limited by 65k and it can't be higher than 65k