# Graylog2 -> Is it possible to export the full_message (raw data) of an especific source? I mean the full_message, without any parsing?

Tags: logging, graylog2

I have some logs that graylog2 is receiving using syslog input plugin.

I need to export them in the same format that i received, without any parsing, so I can send to the application support team.

I have setted the INPUT to keep the full_massage, but i dont know, how i can get them.

I have tried to export using the Export buttom (CSV), but the output, is not on full_message.

Is that possible ?

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

To export the 'full_message' field as a CSV file:

- Click on 'all fields' in the sidebar; this will reveal 'full_message' as a selectable field.
- Select 'full_message'.
- Export as CSV, then it will be in the CSV output.

Note: The CSV will always include the timestamp column, even if you only select 'full message', but you can always import into Excel and delete that column.

*This feature has been available since [Graylog 1.1.0-beta.2](http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.1/pages/changelog.html#graylog-1-1-0-beta-2).*

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Graylog2 REST APIs to get any search result or single message as JSON. That JSON will include the raw message.

Comment: See [Searching for Gray Log 2 API or a way to query ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812470/searching-for-gray-log-2-api-or-a-way-to-query-elasticsearch) for more information on the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Graylog becomes unresponsive when I click "all fields".

My work-around is to modify the ReST call (in the address bar). I change ...fields=message... to be ...fields=full_message..., and hit enter to rerun the call. This reloads the page, and you can then export the csv file as normal, and it now includes the full_message field.